# How to adapt bin/hdfs for executing from outside $HADOOP_HOME/bin?

Tags: bash, hadoop, exec, relative-path, hdfs

I'm trying to modify the [hdfs](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/hdfs/tags/release-0.21.0/bin/hdfs?view=markup) script so that it still functions although not located in $HADOOP_HOME/bin anymore, but when I execute the modified hdfs I get:

```
hdfs: line 110: exec: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell: not found
```

line 110 is:

```
exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
```

I've highlighted the changes I made to the script:

```
bin=**"$HADOOP_HOME"/bin # was** `dirname "$0"`
bin=`cd "$bin"; pwd`

./**hdfs-config.sh # was .** "$bin"/hdfs-config.sh
```

-

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 0.20.3-SNAPSHOT
Subversion http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20-append -r 1041718
Compiled by hammer on Mon Dec  6 17:38:16 CET 2010
```

Comment: Why are you trying to execute the script from another location? There may be other ways to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @Nija - The hadoop cluster has an elder version where hdfs script is not present and I don't have write access. That said, can we focus on the general problem?

Comment: Indeed we should focus on the general problem: You don't have write access and you are trying desperately to work around that problem instead of solving it. That said: _WHY_ are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Nija - no the problem posted here is the error reported with line 110. I have a script that uses hdfs script but on one instance the hadoop available doesn't have it. I either modify the script to work without hdfs or do solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply put a second copy of Hadoop on the system and let it have a different value for HADOOP_HOME?

Comment: Please, delete this answer and make it a comment. I've to re-use the same hadoop copy.